# Add PS Profile to a new local user

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to create a Powershell profile for a new local user. This new local user is just a copy of Administrator account.

My function function works when profile has been initialized. But it don't work when the Windows profile is not created yet (user still not logged in since the creation of account).

Here is my try:

```
function add-PSProfile
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param
    (
        [Parameter( Mandatory=$true )]
        $Login,
        [Parameter( Mandatory=$true )]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
        $RemoteProfilePath
    )

    # Get default profiles directory
    $ProfilesDirectory = ( Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList' -ErrorAction Stop ).ProfilesDirectory

    $ProfilePath       = Join-Path $ProfilesDirectory $Login
    $PSProfilePath     = Join-Path $ProfilePath 'Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1'

    if( -not ( Test-Path $PSProfilePath ) )
    {
        New-Item -ItemType File -Path $PSProfilePath -Force
    }

    Copy-Item $RemoteProfilePath $PSProfilePath
}
```

Do you have any suggestion?
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Use a system wide profile instead of copying to individual accounts? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613488(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I've already thought about your idea, but I really need an user wide profile. I cannot apply the profile to all user.
Some people will require their own profile, some other not...

Comment: So use a common one and users that need their own can still create one (and theirs will take precedence). I don't see how you can copy a file to a profile that doesn't exist yet. Maybe you could use a GPO to write the profile during logon.